# is Raphaël using canvas or svg?

Tags: jquery, canvas, svg, raphael

I've been looking for a good vector solution, and have heard good things about Raphaël. But all over its docs it talks about defining canvases, which just made me confused.

Is Raphaël a canvas or SVG library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to facilitate cross browser support, Raphael uses both VML and SVG.

Reference

- https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael

Comment: Pretty confusing. Then I suppose all that stuff about 'canvas' is THEIR canvas in general and not HTML5 canvas. Pretty lame?

Comment: HTML5 didn't define the word "canvas".

Comment: And it breaks out cross-browser support, as far as on Android (2.x) SVG does not work, but HTML5 canvas is. The only thing is really missing for me in Raphael is support for HTML5 canvas :(

Answer (score 4):

When raphael says canvas it is own terminology and it is not referencing to the HTML5 canvas. It is a layer on top of SVG.